# Condensation without nuclei or solid surface

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensation

I have a question regarding condensation. I have been taught that small particles acting as condensation nuclei are necessary for condensation to occur in clouds as surface tension becomes too strong for small droplets to form under those conditions.

If we consider a boiling pot of water on the stove in a kitchen with completely pure air without any small particles at ambient standard atmospheric pressure and room temperature. Would we be able to observe condensation of the water vapor above the pot? What is the requirement for condensation to occur without nuclei?

Best regards
Tomas

Comment: It would happen but it would just be rare because of the large free energy barrier that must be overcome to form each droplet. The process is pretty well-described by [classical nucleation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_nucleation_theory).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does "rare" in this context mean that most of the condensed droplets that we observe over a boiling pot in a regular kitchen are originating from condensation nuclei (just like clouds)?